# FeignClient duplicate invoke remote method

Tags: java

i want  use invoke a remote method by use feignclient,but the remote method was execute duplicate ,this is my code(i'm not good at english,so fogive me)

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
@Named("cdProductTemplateView")
public class CdProductTemplateView extends BaseView {
    public void cdPost() {
 //cdProTempContext,just a bean
    cdProductClient.cdPost(cdProTempContext);
}

}
```

client:

```
@FeignClient(value = "service", path = "/cdproduct")
public interface CdProductClient {
@RequestMapping("/cdPost")
CdProduct cdPost(@RequestBody CdProductTemplateContext 
     cdProTempContext) throws BusinessException, SystemException;
}
```

controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/cdproduct")
    @RestController
    public class CdProductController{
        public CdProduct cdPostProduct(CdProductTemplateContext cdProTempContext, String resPath)
                throws BusinessException, SystemException {

            return cdProductService.cdPostProduct(cdProTempContext, resPath);
        }
        @RequestMapping("/cdPost")
        public CdProduct cdPost(@RequestBody CdProductTemplateContext cdProTempContext, HttpServletRequest request) {
            return cdPostProduct(cdProTempContext, resPath);
        }
    }
```

serviceImpl：

```
    @Named("cdProductService")
    public class CdProductServiceImpl implements CdProductService {
        @Override
        public CdProduct cdPostProduct(CdProductTemplateContext 
          cdProTempContext, String resPath) throws BusinessException, SystemException {
        //proPkgRequset: a bean ProductPackageRequest 
         cdProService.submitProductPackage(proPkgRequset);
         //this just invoke method(ICDMarketplaceAPIService.submitProductPackage )

        }
    }
```

ICDMarketplaceAPIService

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.***.com", name = "IMarketplaceAPIService")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface  ICDMarketplaceAPIService {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "SubmitProductPackage")
    @Action(input = "http://www.***.com/IMarketplaceAPIService/SubmitProductPackage", output = "http://www.***.com/IMarketplaceAPIService/SubmitProductPackageResponse")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "SubmitProductPackage", targetNamespace = "http://www.***.com", className = "SubmitProductPackage")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "SubmitProductPackageResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.***.com", className = "SubmitProductPackageResponse")
    @WebResult(name = "SubmitProductPackageResult", targetNamespace = "http://www.***.com")
    public ProductIntegrationReportMessage submitProductPackage(
            @WebParam(name = "headerMessage", targetNamespace = "http://www.***.com")
                    HeaderMessage headerMessage,
            @WebParam(name = "productPackageRequest", targetNamespace = "http://www.***.com")
                    ProductPackageRequest productPackageRequest
    );
}
```

when client invoke remote method,the remote method(controller.cdPost,it was execute duplicate ),but if i remove method(ICDMarketplaceAPIService.submitProductPackage, or not use it) or invoke other method (like query),it's ok.What causes the situation to happen, can anyone help me?

Comment: Just wondering: why do you use that "@Named" annotation to give a name that has different casing (starting with lower case)?

Comment: that is used for page ,i think it's not important, so not gived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following code in application.yml:

```
ribbon:
  # Max number of retries on the same server (excluding the first try)
  MaxAutoRetries: 0
  # Max number of next servers to retry (excluding the first server)
  MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 0
```